# How to install phpMyAdmin maintaining older version of php? Linux Fedora 14

Tags: php, linux, installation

I'm running on php 5.2.6 on my development server and need to install phpMyAdmin. However, when I install phpMyAdmin, it updates my php to 5.3.x and that causes my website to break... Been looking online but haven't found anything that will install phpMyAdmin but leave alone the php version.

Anyone know how to install phpMyAdmin without upgrading php automatically? Leave php version alone, just install the phpMyAdmin on Linux Fedora 14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just download it from [here](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php). Don't use yum to install this package.